# How can I manipulate SQL Server CE 4.0 Database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-ce

I have created a CE 4.0 database using visual studio. But now I want to set up tables etc. I need a CE database administrator as management studio 2008 doesn't like it.

Any ideas on the best free tool? I used CEQuery 6 but it doesn't let me connect to a 4.0 database....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can open a SQL Compact DB (.sdf) in Visual Studio which will add your SDF under the "Server Explorer" window's "Data Connections" and allow you to enumerate, create, modify and delete tables etc.

MS is working on improved tools for working with SQL Compact. ETA unknown.

Comment: But you must install VS 2010 SP1 + SQL Server Compact 4.0 tools. You can alos use WebMatrxi and I have a list of 3rd party tools here: http://erikej.blogspot.com/2009/04/sql-compact-3rd-party-tools.html

Answer (score 0):

I've used Fly Howard in the past and it works with version CE 4.0.  It's not free (£25 or approx $38) but worth it in IMO.  Here's the link [Fly Howard](http://www.flyhoward.com/SDF_Viewer.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Erik Ej's blog [Everything SQL Server Compact](http://erikej.blogspot.com/) is a great resource for info and tools.

His masterpiece is the [SQL Server Compact Toolbox](http://sqlcetoolbox.codeplex.com/) - a Visual Studio Add-In for handling and dealing with SQL Server CE database files. Highly recommended !

[image]